# Convolution with indicator function

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

I have to compute the convolution
$$\chi_{[1,2]}(x)e^{-x}*xe^{-x}$$
which is
$$f(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \chi_{[1,2]}(x)e^{-x}(t-x)e^{-(t-x)} \, dx$$
and becomes
$$\int_{1}^2 e^{-x}(t-x)e^{x-t} \, dx=e^{-t}\int_{1}^2 (t-x) \, dx = e^{-t}(t-\frac{3}{2})$$
however, the right solution should be
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & t<1\\
\frac{(t-1)^2}{2}e^{-t} & 1\le t<2\\
(t-\frac{3}{2})e^{-t} & t\ge 2
\end{cases}$$

Is there something I am missing? I don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: Well $e^{-x}\cdot e^{t-x} = e^{t-2x}$, but I don't think that will fix everything.

Comment: I made a mistake in the text of the problem, is not so stupid

Comment: The convolution is correct. The given solution could be wrong or, if this is part of a larger problem, you might want to check whether $f(t)$ is defined for all values of $t$ in the same manner.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote $\chi_{[1,2]}(x)e^{-x}*xe^{-x}.$

I wonder if the second function was intended to be understood as $\chi_{[0,+\infty)}(x) xe^{-x}.$ There are contexts in which one works only with functions whose domain is $[0,+\infty)$ and then that understanding is often conventional. In such contexts one has
$$
(f*g)(t) = \int_0^t f(x)g(t-x)\,dx.
$$

Then you would have
\begin{align}
& \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \chi_{[1,2]}(x) e^{-x} \chi_{[0,+\infty)}(t-x)\cdot (t-x) e^{-(t-x)} \, dx \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_0^t \chi_{[1,2]}(x) e^{-x} (t-x) e^{-(t-x)} \, dx.
\end{align}
If $t\ge2$ then $t-x\ge0$ whenever $1\le x\le 2$ and you get exactly the answer that you got.

If $1\le t<2$ then $t-x\ge 0$ when $1\le x\le t$ so you evaluate $\displaystyle\int_1^t \cdots \, dx.$

If $t<1$ then $t-x <0$ when $1\le x\le 2$ so the value of the integral would be $0.$